# Добавление discord.py бота в группу

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Возможно ли как-нибудь пригласить бота не на сервер, а в группу?[image: вот в эту группу]

Или чтобы бот переходил по ссылке-приглашению отправленную ему?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, это невозможно, дискорд этого не предусмотрел

Answer (score 2):

Бота невозможно пригласить в групповой чат.